# How to combine rigid body animation with character rig?

Tags: animation

Pardon my ignorance, I'm inexperienced and not sure how to search for what I want to do. I want to rig a character with multiple visible components (such as a robot, lego-person, or spooky skeleton).

There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube that demonstrate how to add animations to such characters, but I want to create a character spawn animation where the pieces of the assemble themselves by their visible components. There are tutorials showing rigid body like objects (such as buildings) that can be constructed procedurally, but I'm not sure if these ideas can be combined; or if I need to do something else entirely to accomplish this but my vocabulary is too limited to properly search.

I don't know if it's a necessary detail, but I'd like this to be exportable for consumption by a game-engine so I'm hoping this has an answer that is general and not only suitable for a pre-rendered video output.

Comment: Heya, I'm just spitballing here because I don't know the details of what you wish to do, so I just try to hint with some vocabulary.
I'm guessing the lego-parts are lying on the ground and spawn in as well?
Take the individual LegoParts to a program like Blender and assemble them like you wish to have them in the end, then start rigging the character (meaning to assign/parent  Bones (of an Armature) to the individual parts), and then make two poses one of the deconstructed character and one of the constructed one and interpolate/animate with more detail between the pose with keyframes.. GL!

Comment: @AMNOFFICIAL Yeah that is the general idea. So I guess I'll ask; can I use the same file with both types of animations without them conflicting? I'm used to photoshop, but I guess I'm not sure I understand how blender relates in this situation. Meaning, if I animate an object together and then put the rigging at the end of that animation, is that not retroactive or does the rigging only take place from that moment on?